# How can I access errno from Python's CFFI?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I'm using `cffi` to wrap a library that uses `errno` to return error values.

How can I read `errno` from cffi?

Comment: [Docs](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.6/) seen to indicate `ffi.errno` where `ffi` is instance of `cffi.FFI()`.

Comment: D'oh! Odd that's only in a changelog. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See docs https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.6/

`ffi.errno` is a property of the `cffi.FFI` object.

e.g.

```
from cffi import FFI    
ffi = FFI()
# error happens
print ffi.errno
```

> ffi.errno: the value of errno received from the most recent C call in this thread, and passed to the following C call, is available via reads and writes of the property ffi.errno. On Windows we also save and restore the GetLastError() value, but to access it you need to declare and call the GetLastError() function as usual.